# How to read excel data to datatable using OPENXML?

Tags: asp.net, excel, c#-4.0, excel-interop

I want to read data from an excel file and want to store it in a **datatable**. Previously I was using **interop** **excel**.But it give COM exception many time.So I want to switch to **OPENXML**. But I am unable to read xls file in it .It is showing ***Corrupted data exception***.Any 1 has sample code to fix it.
Which is better to read excel file ?

Is dere any way to stop **COM exception** ?

Which is best oledb vs excel interop vs open xml ?

I donot want any formating .Just want to read data from excel file to datatable. Excel sheet can have foreign characters like japanese, chinese letters.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue. OPEN XML works great with XLSX format but not able to read XLS file. **The root cause is that XLS file formats are saved actually as BINARAY FILE FORMAT. It do not support XMLformatting.** Later versions supports XML formatting therefore it works.

**For Work arround instead to go with OPEN XML, we can go for OLEDB connection, to read XLS file format.** XLSX will only be read by 64bit version - **MS Access Database Engine 2010 64bit Redistrubtion** but it fails in reading XLS formats. **And we cann't install both 32bit & 64bit engines together.**

Excel Interop service (.dll) can be used but it comes with MS Office and on server it is not recommended to install MS Office.